# In C how do i scan from a file and compare with another scan

Tags: c, scanf, strcmp

Why does my code not compare my strings properly, it does not exit the do loop even when I enter same as from the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char ISBN[100];
    char ISBN1[100];
    char BT [512];
    float BP;
    int dis;
    int quant;

    FILE *fp;

    fp=fopen("bookstore.txt", "r");
    printf("\nEnter the ISBN:");
    scanf("%s", ISBN);
    do
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%[^':']:%[^':']:%f:%d:%d",ISBN1, BT, &BP, &dis, &quant);
        }
    while(strcmp(ISBN, ISBN1) !=0);
    printf("%.2f", BP);
}
```

This is the data my the file contains:

```
9780273776840:C How to Program:95.90:30:0  
9780131193710:The C Programming Language:102.90:20:30  
9780470108543:Programming fo Dummies:60.20:25:50  
9781118380932:Hacking for Dummies:50.90:78:0  
9781939457318:The 20/20 Diet:80.90:73:10
```

Comment: What does "it wont work" mean? How are the variables declared?

Comment: Please add the code part where you declare the variables and the actual behaviour

Comment: Please provide a complete and verifiable example, the above code does not compile.

Comment: try `" %[^:]:%[^:]:%f:%d:%d"`

Comment: The things that happens is, i enter the 1st ISBN no. from the file and it works, but then once i use the 2nd or 3rd or 4th, it gets stuck in a infinite loop, i'm assuming this is due to the while condition not being met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your loop as follows -

```
 if(fp!=NULL){                         // checking success of fopen
while(fscanf(fp," %[^:]:%[^:]:%f:%d:%d",ISBN1, BT, &BP, &dis, &quant)==5){   //check success of fscanf

       if(strcmp(ISBN,ISBN1)==0){     // compare both strins 
               break;                 // if equal break 
          }
      }
 printf("\n%.2f", BP);                // print corresponding value
}
```

Using `fscanf` as condition for your `while` loop (loop will iterate until `fscanf` fails )-

```
while(fscanf(fp," %[^:]:%[^:]:%f:%d:%d",ISBN1, BT, &BP, &dis, &quant)==5)
   /*            ^ don't forget to put this space its intentionally there */
```

Also note the changes made in `fscanf`'s format specifiers .

### EDIT

Whole program -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
     FILE *fp;
     char ISBN[50],ISBN1[50],BT[50];
     int dis,quant;
     float BP;
     fp=fopen("Results.txt","r");
     scanf("%s", ISBN);

     if(fp!=NULL){
        while(fscanf(fp," %[^:]:%[^:]:%f:%d:%d",ISBN1, BT, &BP, &dis, &quant)==5){

            if(strcmp(ISBN,ISBN1)==0) 
                 break;
          }
        printf("\n%.2f", BP);
        fclose(fp);
      }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using this, evn if the ISBN's dnt match it breaks :\

Comment: @MuntaseerAlam  Did you forgot the space before `fscanf` ? Because it worked perfectly for me .

Comment: Would u please post your whole source code, it would help alot.

Comment: @MuntaseerAlam Yes , sure .

Comment: @MuntaseerAlam I have posted program .Please take a look .

Comment: For some reason this is not working on mine, i'm using codeblocks btw and am quite new to coding. I do understand your code, but in mine it isnt working. Mine just exits without printing anything regardless of ISBNs matching or not. :\

Comment: @MuntaseerAlam I tried it on code blocks also , but I work correctly for me .

Answer (score 0):

OP is certainly having problems with entering a title with spaces in it like "C How to Program" which will only populate `ISBN` with `"C"`.

The key problem is using `scanf()` and `fscanf()` incorrectly. Rather than mess with that approach, uses `fgets()` to read user input and file input and then process the data that was read.

```
char ISBN[100+2]; // +1 \n \0
printf("\nEnter the ISBN:");
fgets(ISBN, sizeof ISBN, stdin);
ISBN[strcspn(ISBN, "\r\n")] = 0; // lop off end-of-line of line chars

char fileline[700];
while (fgets(fileline, sizeof fileline, fp)) {
  if (sscanf(fileline,"%99[^:]:%511[^:]:%f:%d:%d",ISBN1, BT, &BP, &dis, &quant) == 5) {
    if (strcmp(ISBN, ISBN1) == 0) {
      printf("%.2f", BP);
    }
  }
}
```